# Geometric Applications of Calculus: find the equation of the tangent

Tags: calculus

I'm not able to solve this problem: Find the equation of the tangent to the function $f(x) = \frac{5}{x} + 2x$ which passes through the point $P=(0,-4)$. Also give the coordinates of the tangent point $B$ and the angle of intersection between $t$ and $f$.

I have already taken the derivative of the function: $f'(x) = -\frac{5}{x^2} +2$ but when I plugged $P=(0,-4)$ it did not work because I got $f'(0) = -\frac{5}{0^2} +2$. Then I got error because I can't divide by zero.

Thank you for helping!!

Comment: It's not $f(x)$ that passes through $(0,-4)$ but a tangent from $f(x)$.

Comment: Is $t$ the line passing through $P$ and tangent to the graph of $f$? By plugging $0$ into $f’$ you would only compute the image of $0$ through $f’$ (which is not related to your question), but as you noticed, $f’$ is **not** defined for $x=0$

Comment: To give you some further insight: The slope of a linear function (line going through zero, y = bx) is really the height of that function one unit away from the origin (rise over run, but that's just the rise when run is 1). To get a value at any other distance, you multiply the slope by that distance. Now, $f'(a)$ gives you the slope of the tangent line, which we now assume is "attached" to the function at $(a, f(a))$, rather than to the origin. Now the "run" is the (signed) horizontal distance form $a$, which is $(x-a)$. Do the "slope $\times$ run", then add $f(a)$ to move the line vertically

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tangent line to the point $(a, 5/a+2a)$ has the slope $f’(a)=-5/a^2+2$. So the tangent line equation is

$$y= f’(a)(x-a)+f(a)$$

$$y= (-5/a^2+2)(x-a)+ 5/a+2a$$

$$y= (-5/a^2+2)x+10/a.$$

Put $(0,-4)$ in this: $$-4=10/a.$$

So $$a=-2.5.$$

The coordinates of the intersection point are $$(-2.5, -7).$$ The tangent line equation is then $$y=1.2x-4.$$

Answer (score 1):

I graphed it on Desmos and adjusted the slope and it listed one point of "intersection" when I set the slope to 1.2:[image]